# how to modify a specific part of a string that contains a specific symbol and modify it

Tags: javascript, html, string

I want to modify all parts of srings that has text between two primes (prime = ')

lets say i have this paragraph in my database:
**Meter'2'. Kilometer'2'. mile'2'.**

and I want to change it to:
**Meter². Kilometer². mile².**

..........

like this change in the HTML:
`<p>Meter'2'. Kilometer'2'. mile'2'.</p>`

to:
`<p>Meter<sup>2</sup>. Kilometer<sup>2</sup>. mile<sup>2</sup>.</p>`

..........

is that possible to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to treat as a string, you can do it using a simple [regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```js
const string = "<p>Meter'2'. Kilometer'2'. mile'2'.</p>";

console.log(string.replace(/'([^']+)'/g, "<sup>$1</sup>"));
```

It matches anything wrapped by `'`, and store the value as a group, then it uses that value (`$1`, group one) when replaces the occurrence found.

After that, you can insert the resulting string as HTML using [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) for example.

Comment: it just makes one problem, the <sup> tag wont work and it shows just like a string in the text

Comment: As mentioned, you need to use `innerHTML` to "transform" that string in HTML. Until then, as wrote, you're using it just as text, as the `console.log` shows. But if you do something like, I don't know, `document.body.innerHTML = string.replace(/'([^']+)'/g, "<sup>$1</sup>")` that would work. Or any other HTML element that supports innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const str = '<p>Meter'2'. Kilometer'2'. mile'2'.</p>'

str.replace(/'(\d)'/g, '<sup>$1</sup>')
```

The parenthesis put every number inside simple quotes into $1, so you can put anything you want around it.

Comment: I tried it and it make the code like this: <p>Meter<sup>2</sup>. Kilometer<sup>2</sup>. mile<sup>2</sup></p> and it shows like: Meter<sup>2</sup>. Kilometer<sup>2</sup>. mile<sup>2</sup> i mean it wont change the styling, it just adds this texts in the p tag